# axios.post results in Bad request - grant_type:'client_credentials'

Tags: node.js, post, oauth-2.0, axios, fiware

My axios POST method is not working fine. While the call syntax appears to be correct, I guess there is somewhat deep-rooted issue in my specific case. I am trying to get access token using grant_type=client_credentials, using a POST request to fiware IDM server. The call results in `400: bad request`.

curl command works just great. It seems there is a CORS violation when I use simple http request, hence I switched to using node. I tried axios by sending data in separate body, it didn't work either, then someone suggested to send the data in the call using axios.post, it also ended in same problem. Note: I have tried `grant_type=password`, however, that also met same fate.

```
axios.post('https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token',{ 
'grant_type':'client_credentials'},{
headers: 
{
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
'Authorization': 'Basic xxxx'   
}

}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error.response.data.error);
    })
```

I expect to get the access token, however, I am getting error 400 as below:

```
{ message: 'grant_type missing in request body: {}',
code: 400,
title: 'Bad Request' }
```

Comment: could you also post the working curl?

Comment: Sure.. here it..

Comment: curl -v --insecure -X POST http://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:Basic xxxx" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is because the host at `https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token` expects body data to be `x-www-form-urlencoded` but `axios` is converting the body to `json` for you. That is the default behaviour with `axios`.

Change your axios code to send `x-www-form-urlencoded` body data like:

```
// use querystring node module
var querystring = require('querystring');

axios.post('https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token',{
  // note the use of querystring
  querystring.stringify({'grant_type':'client_credentials'}),{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
    'Authorization': 'Basic xxxx'   
  }
}).then(...
```

Comment: Problem is with raw query string. So after using querystring.stringify({'grant_type':'client_credentials'}) It worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks! tried to edit now, too many edits pending... please can someone remove the curly at the end of the 2nd line of code. Shouldn't be there